# Simplest high order components and material-ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

When I'm using TextField directly from my component it works perfectly fine (case 1), however when I'm wrapping it inside function (case 2) from props it loosing focus after one each change.

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

var Comp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {description: ""};
    },
    descriptionChanged: function (e) {
        this.setState({description: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var T2 = function (props) {
            return <TextField hintText="Desc2"
                              value={self.state.description}
                              onChange={self.descriptionChanged}/>;
        };
        return <div>
            1 <TextField hintText="Desc1"
                       value={self.state.description}
                       onChange={self.descriptionChanged}
            />
            2 <T2/>
        </div>

    }
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4mmnjjay/)

Why it's happening and how I can fix it?

Comment: I recommend adding a [mcve] so we can help assist you better. A jsfiddle/similar would go a long way.

Comment: @FrankerZ:  updated with jsfiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are making a *new* function (and thus a new high order component) each time you render.  React will think this is a completely different type of component and will destroy the old DOM to make the new.

In this version we make the high order component *once* when your component instance is created.

```
import TextField from 'material-ui/TextField';

var Comp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return {description: ""};
    },
    componentWillMount() {
        // create HOC once for this instance
        var self = this;
        this.T2 = function (props) {
            return <TextField hintText="Desc2"
                              value={self.state.description}
                              onChange={self.descriptionChanged}/>;
        };
    },
    descriptionChanged: function (e) {
        this.setState({description: e.target.value});
    },
    render: function () {
        var self = this;
        var T2 = this.T2;
        return <div>
            1 <TextField hintText="Desc1"
                       value={self.state.description}
                       onChange={self.descriptionChanged}
            />
            2 <T2/>
        </div>

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do you know any way to get rid of `var T2 = this.T2;` notion? It would improve solution so much.

Comment: Or, if there are few of them, compact them into one statement somehow.

Comment: `var { T1, T2, T3, T4 } = this;` will assign `this.T1` and `this.T2` and `this.T3` to local variables...